# How to load a folder of files to databricks filestore?

Tags: databricks

I have folder called data containing multiple csv, json, parquet files. How can i load the whole folder to dbfs filestore. All options i found are of selecting files individually, multiple files but still as seperate files.

```
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
#this is for a single file , how to load a folder?
```

Can anyone plzz help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try: dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
this recursively puts local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana

Link: https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#dbfs

Answer (score 0):

Currently Compressed files such as zip and tar files are not supported.
The file must be a CSV or TSV and have the extension “.csv” or “.tsv”.
The upload UI supports uploading up to 10 files at a time
The total size of uploaded files must be under 100 megabytes.